# How can I read and set a variable in another class?

Tags: ios, swift

In my searches, I see this is a common question but I've tried some of the solutions and haven't been able to resolve. A simple example below. When I run the app, and press button, 0 prints as expected. After pressing button2, then button, 1 prints, also as expected. If I move the picker, then press button, I expect 2, but still get 1.

I gather this is because ViewController().sample() is creating a copy, and not actually changing the variable in the "original" ViewController(). I'm stumped at what needs to be reconfigured to get the desired behavior.

```
import UIKit

class pickerHelper: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    let data: [String]
    init(data: [String]) {
        self.data = data
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        data.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        data[row]
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        ViewController().sample()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        p1.delegate = helper1
        p1.dataSource = helper1
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var p1: UIPickerView!

    let helper1 = pickerHelper(data:["a", "b", "c"])
    var test = Int()

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        print(test)
    }

    @IBAction func button2(_ sender: Any) {
        test = 1
    }

    func sample() {
        test = 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a situation where you would either use a delegation pattern or a callback closure; this latter is more "Swifty".

With delegation:

```
protocol PickerHelperDelegate {
    func pickerHelper(_ helper: selectedRow row:)
}
```

Then in your `PickerHelper` you add a delegate property and invoke the delegate when required:

```
class PickerHelper: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    let data: [String]

    var delegate: PickerHelperDelegate? 

    init(data: [String]) {
        self.data = data
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        data.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        data[row]
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        self.delegate?.pickerHelper(self, selectedRow: row)
    }
}
```

In your view controller you need to assign the delegate and implement the protocol function:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        p1.delegate = helper1
        p1.dataSource = helper1
        helper1.delegate = self // Assign this object as the picker helper's delegate
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var p1: UIPickerView!

    let helper1 = pickerHelper(data:["a", "b", "c"])
    var test = Int()
}

extension ViewController: PickerHelperDelegate {
    func pickerHelper(_ helper: PickerHelper, selectedRow row:Int) {
        self.sample()
        print("Selected row \(row)")
    }
}
```

You can do a similar thing with a closure:

```
class PickerHelper: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    let data: [String]

    var changeHandler: ((Int)->Void)? 

    init(data: [String]) {
        self.data = data
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        data.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        data[row]
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        self.changeHandler?(row)
    }
}
```

In your view controller you need to assign a closure to the `changeHandler` property:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     p1.delegate = helper1
     p1.dataSource = helper1
     helper.changeHandler = { row in 
         self.sample()
         print("Selected row \(row)")
    }
}
```

You could also change your protocol or closure to pass back the `data` element rather than just the row number and use generics for your `PickerHelper` so that it wasn't just limited to strings.

Note that classes start with a capital by convention, so you should say `PickerHelper`, not `pickerHelper`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static property to keep its state in class.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        p1.delegate = helper1
        p1.dataSource = helper1
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var p1: UIPickerView!

    let helper1 = pickerHelper(data:["a", "b", "c"])
    static var test = Int()

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        print(test)
    }

    @IBAction func button2(_ sender: Any) {
        ViewController.test = 1
    }

    static func sample() {
        test = 2
    }
}
```

Comment: That probably isn't the best approach.